# AngularJS UI Router creates no href

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I am new to AngularJS and i am playing a bit with the routes. But the UI Router does not "convert" my URL to he correct href Attribute.

**My View:**

```
<a ui-sref="music.detail({postID: post.id})" class="text-ellipsis">{{post.first_name}}</a>
```

**And this is from my router.js**

```
.state('music.detail', {
    url: '/{postId}',
    templateUrl: 'tpl/music.detail.html'
})
```

But the HTML Output is still without the ID. `{{post.id}}` is working fine and returns the ID of the JSON Object.

```
<a ui-sref="music.detail({postID: post.id})" class="text-ellipsis ng-binding" href="#/music/">Tremaine Stehr</a>
```

Am i something missing here?

Comment: is this regex appropriate here? `/{postId:[0-9]{1,4}}'`

Comment: there is typo in your code. you should use 'postId' instead of 'postID'

Comment: I changed it to `/{postID}`. But does this belongs to the href problem? I dont get is why ..

Comment: glad I helped :):) I have posted an answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

check your html

```
<a ui-sref="music.detail({postId: post.id})" class="text-ellipsis ng-binding" >Tremaine Stehr</a>
```